# Lexical or Preprocessor Issue 'ParseFacebookUtils/PFFacebookUtils.h' file not found

Tags: parse-platform, xcode5.1, parsefacebookutils

I am getting the below error within AppDelegate.m while trying to run my app. I have removed and re-added the FacebookSDK.framework in hopes that it will help however, it did not. My deployment target is 7.1 and I am using Xcode 5.1.1

Lexical or Preprocessor Issue **'ParseFacebookUtils/PFFacebookUtils.h' file not found** on the line below

```
 #import <ParseFacebookUtils/PFFacebookUtils.h>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to delete derived data, run clean, and checked that the framework is linked in the target build settings?

Comment: @TomErikStøwer Thank you for the suggestions. Yes, I have tried all of that my issue still persist. I have been working on this for a day now any other suggestions?

Comment: From the screenshot it looks like the FacebookSDK.framework and ParseFacebookUtils.framework files aren't actually there, since they are red. You should try and copy the frameworks into the project again.

Comment: @TomErikStøwer thank you. I've been staring at this screen for too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"ParseFacebookUtils" and "FacebookSDK" are two different frameworks. You get error ParseFacebookUtils.framework, and as I can see from screenshot it is missing. Try to reload it (you can find it in parse-library archive).